# Como pegar valores de dois fomulários separados por apenas um submit?

Tags: php

Tenho dois formulários na mesma página (bem separados por tags html) e preciso pegar os dados dos dois para meu script PHP.
Como sou novíssimo em PHP e não faço ideia, chutei uma tentativa acionando o PHP nos dois forms e pondo o input=submit apenas em 1 deles, tipo:

```
<form action="meu.php" metod="POST">
conteudo do form1
</form>
<-tags HTML, como div,a,center etc->
<form action="meu.php" metod="POST">
conteúdo do form2
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

pois é, não fazia muito sentido e vi que que não rola. Dei uma pesquisada mas também não achei nada útil.
Posso fazer algo para que isso seja possivel? (esse exemplo serve pra mostrar como está a estrutura do meu código)

Comment: Obviamente os `names` dos elementos dos forms são diferentes, não é?

Comment: O primeiro form tem botão submit?

Comment: @dvd o primeiro não tem submit, pq só preciso usar os dados dele na mesma página, daí uso JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar JavaScript para injetar no segundo `form` os elementos do primeiro. Para isso eu criei dinamicamente uma `div` oculta (`display: none;`) no segundo `form` e inseri o conteúdo do primeiro. Ao submeter, será enviado tudo junto.

Para isso, coloquei `id`s nos dois formulários para facilitar a seleção no JavaScript e adicionei `onsubmit` no segundo para chamar a função.

O HTML ficaria assim:

```
<form id="form1" action="meu.php" method="POST">
   conteúdo do form1
</form>
<form id="form2" action="meu.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return formularios()">
   conteúdo do form2
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

E o JavaScript:

```
function formularios(){

   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.setAttribute("id","divoculta");
   div.style.display = "none";
   document.querySelector("#form2").appendChild(div);
   var form1html = document.querySelector("#form1").innerHTML;
   document.querySelector("#divoculta").innerHTML = form1html;

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Nem testei, mas observando a lógica vi que faz sentido! muito obrigado, me salvou :p

Comment: Se quiser dar uma testada rápida neste link: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php